# Replace an Existing App on Apple Store with a new One

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am working with a client who has an existing app in the market that isn’t performing quite as well as expected, and for several reasons this has led to the development of a totally new app that they want to roll out this year.

They have an existing user base that we would want to migrate over to the new app, but we are not sure which is the best approach to reduce the number of users dropping off. One suggestion is that we just roll this out as an update to the app.

Is that a feasible option, can we upload a new app with the same bundle id so that the old one gets replaced with a new one, and will the user be shown a force upgrade screen?

I am new to this, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to keep the users, you can update the existing app with a different implementation if you use the same bundle identifier. Your users can upgrade, you will keep your ratings, in app purchases/subscriptions and everything will stay as it is. You can also access all the previous data from the existing app (Database, UserDefaults, and so on) to do a proper migration. Testing this is also possible: Install the current app from the app store and deploy your new implementation to the same device via Xcode.

Comment: @mgratzer what about the users who don't have the automatic upgrade enabled, how would they know that they have to upgrade? because the existing app is not being handled by us, it was developed by a different vendor.

Comment: Thats going to be a problem, they won't and you can not contact them unless you have a communication channel (email, push notification, ...). As app developers we always have this problem, e.g. when we increase the minimum required iOS version and users/devices are left behind because they can not update to the latest OS.

This is something one would have had to consider in advance (like having a remote configuration showing an alert when the user start the old/deprecated app). We do this for most apps to be prepared for critical updates.

Answer (score 0):

> can we upload a new app with the same bundle id so that the old one gets replaced with a new one?

**Yes**

> will the user be shown a force upgrade screen?

**No**